# tuned on fedora 22 - setting different alpm policies for specific devices

Tags: linux, fedora, power-management, tuned

I'm trying to configure alpm to max_perfomance on my system disk, medium_power on my data disks and min_power for backup disks. I tried various variations in tuned.conf but the result is that the last setting is set for all my disks.

My tuned.conf file goes like this:

> [systemdisk]
>
> devices=sdb
>
> type=disk
>
> alpm=max_performance
>
> [datadisk]
>
> devices=sda, sdd,!sdb
>
> type=disk
>
> alpm=medium_power
>
> [backupdisk]
>
> type=disk
>
> devices=sdc, sde
>
> alpm=min_power

and the result is that all my disks are set to min_power. If I comment the [backupdisk] section, all my disks are set to medium_power. How can I configure different alpm values for different disks?

Comment: Seems like it might be a bug. Opened bug report @ https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1246992

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an official reply to the bug I opened:
 https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1246992
Unfortunately, the reply is that setting different alpm policies for different devices is not supported. It may be supported in the future for devices on different controllers, but not as a specific setting for different drives.